# What is the measurement for spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I've heard from some places (Stephen Hawking's A Brief History of Time is one of them) that spin is measured as the reciprocal of the number of rotations it takes for a particle to look identical. As such, it is measured in 1/2, 2, 0, etc.

However, I've also heard from other places (such as Veritasium) that spin is measured up or down, and has a probabilistic value until measured, and this phenomenon leads to quantum entanglement and so on.

Can somebody please explain this? Which one is correct? (Or are there different types of quantum mechanical spin?)

Answer (score 1):

Although the statements sound a little vague, both are actually correct. They just refer to different aspects. There are different `kinds' of spin and then each kind can have different values.

As for the different kinds of spin, one can distinguish among scalars, which are spin-zero, fermions (or spinor fields) which are spin-half, and vector boson which are spin-one. The scalars don't have particular spin values so their spin can only be zero. Spin-half fields (like the electrons, or the other fundamental fermions) can take on two possible values: $+1/2$ or $-1/2$, which are often referred to as *spin-up* and *spin-down*, respectively. The spin-one fields (such as the photon or other gauge bosons) can in general take on three possible values $+1$, $0$ or $-1$. However, due to gauge invariance some of these degrees of freedom are not present so that one only gets $\pm 1$.

When one has more than one particle, they can be *entangled* in terms of their spin degrees of freedom. This means that if we measure the spin of one of the particles and find it to be a particular value, then one can already say what the spin of the other particle would be, even without having to measure it. Prior to the initial measurement the spins of these particles could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

The *total spin* of a particle is a fundamental property that describes how the particle behaves with respect to rotations. It is in this sense that, simplifying quite a bit, one can say that the spin measures the number of rotations it takes for a particle to come back to its original state. To be a little more specific, a particle with spin one is described by a wavefunction that comes back to itself after a $2\pi$ rotation, which is the behaviour of an ordinary vector. On the other hand the wavefunction of a spin $1/2$ particle like the electron gains a minus sign after a $2\pi$ rotation, so that it comes back to itself only after a $4\pi$ rotation. Such wavefunction is called a *spinor*.

For a given value of the total spin $s$, there are quantities called *spin components* that can take values from $-s$ to $s$, with integer steps. These can be seen as the projections of the total spin on the coordinate axes, and it is a fundamental fact of quantum mechanics that they can never be measured simultaneously. One can decide to measure one of them (tipically denoted by $S_z$), and will get a value, among those that are allowed,  with a certain probability that depends on the state of the particle. Your example refers to a spin $1/2$ particle. In this case the component $S_z$ can only take the values $\pm 1/2$, which are commonly referred to as "up" or "down". If you read a bit about quantum mechanics, you might have met expressions of the form
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\rvert {1/2,\uparrow}\rangle+\rvert{1/2,\downarrow}\rangle)$$
This describes a quantum state of a particle with total spin of $1/2$ that is in a state for which a measurement of the $S_z$ component will give up or down with the same probability. States with different coefficients will give different probabilities for the "up" or "down" values.

So, to summarize, your first statement refers to the total spin of a particle, which is an intrinsic property that can never change. Your second statement refers to the measurement of the components of the spin, which can give a set of results ("up" or "down" in the simplest case) with certain probabilities, according with the principles of quantum mechanics.